# Business Objects 3.0 to 4.0 Migration Error: NoClassDefFound IStorageManager

Tags: java, upgrade, business-objects

I was in the process of migrating from SAP Business Objects 3.0 to 4.0, and kept running into this error when trying to instantiate the Webi Reporting Engine:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/businessobjects/rebean/internal/util/storage/IStorageManager
>    at com.businessobjects.rebean.fc.internal.ras21.FullClientReportEngineOCCAFactory.makeOCCA(Unknown Source)
>    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngines.createReportEngine(ReportEngines.java:281)
>    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngines.getService(ReportEngines.java:244)
>    ...
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.businessobjects.rebean.internal.util.storage.IStorageManager
>    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
>    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
>    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
>    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:52)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this error; seems I did not have all the JAR files in the classpath. Here is the list of JAR's I needed:

```
bcm.jar 
boconfig.jar 
buplugins.jar 
ccis.jar 
cdz_cluster_mgmt_types_idl.jar 
cdzidl.jar 
ceaspect.jar 
cecore.jar 
celib.jar 
ceplugins_core.jar 
ceplugins_cr.jar 
cereports.jar 
cesdk.jar 
cesession.jar
cfoundation.jar cvom_chart_lib_en.jar 
corbaidl.jar 
cryptojFIPS.jar 
CrystalEnterpriseRepositoryService.jar
CrystalReportSDK.jar 
CTPlugin_idl.jar 
cvom.jar 
cvom_chart_lib.jar 
cvom_en.jar 
cvom_ui_helpers.jar 
dsl_enginer.jar 
dsl_sdk_commands.jar 
dsl_sdk_requests.jar 
dsl_sdk_server.jar 
dsl_sdk_services.jar 
ebus405.jar 
eclipse.emf.ecore_2.4.2.v200902171115.jar 
GenericContainer_idl.jar 
GenericContainer_proxy.jar
guice-1.0.jar 
ie_proxies.jar 
IEPlugin_idl.jar 
inproc_container.jar 
jtools.jar 
logging.jar 
org.eclipse.emf.common_2.4.0.v200902171115.jar org.
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.4.1.v200902171115.jar 
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.4.0.v20080421-2006.jar 
org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.4.0.v20080516-0950.jar 
org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.3.R34x_v20081215-1030.jar 
protobuf.jar 
ras21core.jar 
ras21dsl.jar 
ras21proc.jar
ras21sdk.jar 
rebean.common.jar
rebean.wi.adapter.jar
rebean.wi.jar
rebean.wi.model.jar
rebean.wi.server.commands.jar
rebean.wi.server.jar
rebean.wi.server.requests.jar
rom.jar 
sdk.core.jar 
sdk.core.server.common.jar 
sdk.core.server.corbra.jar 
sdk.core.server.jar 
sdk.core.session.cms.jar 
sdk.core.sessions.jar 
SL_plugins.jar 
TraceLog.jar 
webi_proxies.jar 
webreporting.jar 
xbean-2.2.0.jar 
xpp3.jar 
xpp3_min.jar 
xpp3_xpath.jar
```